# What are DBAL, DAO, DAL, Model and DLL in PHP

Tags: php, oop, architecture

I want a proper example of the all the layers inside a data tier. What are DBAL, DAO, DAL, Model and DLL? What kind of codes are kept in each layer mentioned?

My general understanding:

**DLL**: Data Logic Layer : A layer controlling action to the database like

```
getLatestNewsRecords();
```

**Model**: A representation of data table, in object format

```
class news {
    public $title;
    public function setTitle() {}
    public fucntion getTitle() {}
}
```

**DAL**: Data Access Layer A layer taking the request for either BLL/DLL along with the Model and doing necessary actions

```
class new {
    public function save(News $news) {
        $date = $news -> getDate();
        $date = strtotime($date);
        $news -> setDate($date);

        $this -> dao -> save($news);
}
```

**DAO**: Data Access Object A layer which get a raw data ready to be interacted with the database

**DBAL**: Database Abstraction Layer: A layer containing interface methods like connections.

```
class news {
    public function save(News $news) {

        $title = $news -> getTitle();
        $dbal = new DBAL();
        $dbal -> query() -> insert("title" => $title");
    }
}
```

Comment: @yes123, I didn't got your point.

Answer (score 0):

I can't call myself a good OOP-programmer, by I think some of these concepts might be originating from different areas of use. Unlikely you will need someday to implement all of these in single product. Better implement some readymade architectural patterns instead of trying to implement individual parts of them. You can start with [Wikipedia article on architectural patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Architectural_pattern_%28computer_science%29#Examples), if you haven't read it before.